# Extension on dictionary type where key and value have specific types

Tags: swift, dictionary

We need to add key value pair in dictionary of type `[String:String]` where value I am trying to add might be optional, but I need to make sure that pairs with optionals that have value are added to the dictionary and others are simply discarded.

I have tried to create an extension on dictionary for this.

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func insert(stringOptinal optional : String?, forStringKey stringKey : String) {
        if let stringValue = optional  {
            self[stringKey as! Key] = stringValue as? Value
        }
    }
}

var dictionary = ["1":"One","2":"Two"]

var serverFetchedStringWithString : String? = "Some String From Server,That ay or may not exists"
var serverFetchedStringWithNil : String?

//Added as key value pair
dictionary.insert(stringOptinal: serverFetchedStringWithString, forStringKey: "3")
// Not added
dictionary.insert(stringOptinal: serverFetchedStringWithNil, forStringKey: "4")

print(dictionary)

var dictionaryOfIntString = [1:"One",2:"Two"]
//An obvious crash as we are trying to insert [String:String] to a dictionary of [Int,String]
dictionaryOfIntString.insert(stringOptinal: serverFetchedStringWithString, forStringKey: "3")
```

This works well for all dictionaries of type `[String:String]`. But crashes when type changes (for example `[Int:String]`).

**EDIT** : The extension I have added is generic version, its valid for dictionaries with Hashable keys and values. How do I make sure this extension to be applicable to dictionaries of type `[String: String]` **ONLY**.

How do I make sure this extension is only valid for dictionaries of type `[String:String]`?

Comment: @Daij-Djan Edited! .Hope it now makes more sense

Comment: @Daij-Djan. Ok, to be more specific, lets forget about the method written in extension. The question is How to create and extension on a generic that work specifically on a given type. Like array can take any generic element, how can I create an extension on this array that only work on array that take only string elements?

Comment: with the second edit it makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can constrain your Dictionary extension to only work apply to keys and values that are `StringLiteralConvertable` by declaring it like this:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: StringLiteralConvertible, Value: StringLiteralConvertible {
    mutating func insert(stringOptinal optional : String?, forStringKey stringKey : String) {
        if let stringValue = optional  {
            self[stringKey as! Key] = stringValue as? Value
        }
    }
}
```

Your example will then generate a compiler error, but at least it won't crash.

Comment: @Daij-Djan this is what I wanted. Thanks for you effort :)